# Calculate Factorial within a single "for" loop to calculate sum of series

Tags: c, visual-studio, for-loop

It took me a while conceptual to grasp how to code a loop that would calculate a given series in which a factorial was used.

I coded it--then my teacher told us we had to use a single `for` loop. I can't seem to grasp how to do something like this. It doesn't make sense how you'd keep the running total of the products across several numbers.

Here is my code; which includes a nested `for` loop. I really appreciate any and all help.

```
int main() {

/*init variables*/
int N; //number of terms
float NUMER, DENOM = 1;
float FRAC, sum = 0, x;

/*asks user for value of N*/
printf("Input number of terms: ");
scanf("%i", &N);

/*asks user for value of x*/
printf("Input value of x: ");
scanf("%f", &x);

for (int n = 0; n <= N; n++) {
    NUMER = (pow(x, n)); //calculates numerator
    for (int fac = 1; fac <= n; fac++) { //calculates factorial using for loop
        DENOM = n * fac;
    }
    if (DENOM <= 0)
        printf("\n\nError, dividing by zero.\n\n"); //this is for debugging purposes; disregard
    FRAC = NUMER / DENOM; //calculates fraction
    sum += FRAC; //running sum of series
}
printf("\nSum of the series is %.1f\n\n", sum); //prints sum of series

return 0;
```

Comment: Be sure to `#include <math.h>`

Comment: @chux I did--I just didn't include it in my code because it was pretty obvious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `DENOM = n!`, so you can just start with `DENOM = 1`
and update the value inside the loop:

```
DENOM = 1;
for (int n = 0; n <= N; n++) {
    NUMER = (pow(x, n)); //calculates numerator

    FRAC = NUMER / DENOM; //calculates fraction
    sum += FRAC; //running sum of series

    DENOM *= n+1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of computing `x^n` and `n!` each time through the outer loop, you can initialize
the quotient to 1.0 before the outer loop, then on each pass through the outer loop,
multiply by `x/n` to get the next term in the series.  This will avoid the need 
to call `pow(x,n)`, and use an inner loop to calculate the factorial, each pass through
the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about what you would do if calculating a factorial by hand, I think you can figure out how to code this pretty easily.

Lets say you are trying to calculate `11!`. Well, you would start at 11, and them multiply by 10. Now you have 110. Now multiply by 9. You have 990. Now multiply by 8...

As you can see, the `11, 10, 9, 8...` series is what your for loop is going to be. Just keep your 'current answer' in a variable and keep multiplying it by the number provided by your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You get a more stable answer working the loop in reverse.  Many infinite sums numerically come out better summing the smallest terms together first.

> f(x,n) = x^0/0! + x^1/1! + x^2/2! + ... + x^n/n!

Let the sum be                     `S(x,n)   = x/n`
Let the sum of the 2 last terms be `S(x,n-1) = x/(n-1) + x/(n-1)*S(x,n)`
Let the sum of the 3 last terms be `S(x,n-2) = x/(n-2) + x/(n-2)*S(x,n-1)`
...
Let the sum of the N last terms be `S(x,1)   = x/(1)   + x/(1)*S(x,1)`

```
double e(double x, unsigned n) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  while (n > 0) {
    sum = x*(1 + sum)/n;
    n--;
  }
  sum += 1.0;  // The zero term
  return sum;
}
```

Notice that even if `n` is large like 1000, and the mathematical answer < DBL_MAX, this loop does not run into floating point overflow so easily.

[edit] But if code must be done in a forward loop, the below calculates each term not as separate products that may overflow, but a unified computation.

```
double e_forward(double x, unsigned n) {
  double sum = 1.0;
  double term = 1.0;
  for (unsigned i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    term *= x / i;
    sum += term;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems...complicated. Terseness is or can be your friend :D

I don't think it needs to be much more complicated than:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

  double limit = 10 ; // how far do we want to go?
  double x     =  2 ; // some value for X
  double xn    =  1 ; // by definition, for all X, X^0 is 1
  double nf    =  1 ; // by convention, 0! is 1
  double value =  0 ;
  double sum   =  0 ;
  double n     =  0 ;

  while ( n < limit )
  {
    value =  xn / nf ; // compute the next element of the series
    sum   += value   ; // add that to the accumulator
    xn    *= x       ; // compute the *next* value for X^n
    nf    *= (++n)   ; // compute the *next* value for N!
  }

  return 0;
}
```